# How to set images in circle view with rotation?

Tags: android

I want to set images in circle view as following.and It should be also rotate like wheel .SO How to set this type of animation in android?
[image]

Comment: let i give you like of example

Answer (score 1):

See this Example , you will find Android 3D Carousel example which matches to your requirement.

[image]

**Updated** :

```
http://stackoverflow.com/q/5503892/1218762![enter image description here][1]

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel
```